# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT in SpriteKit Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've been working on a Flappy Bird clone in SpriteKit and i'm constantly getting the error:

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

on the line of code below.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
```

It seems that this error occurs when this code is inserted:

```
_ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: Selector("makePipes"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

I've looked around on stack overflow and most of the stuff I found did not pertain to SpriteKit. How would i get rid of this error?

Comment: When you are getting the error, can you say what the exact error is in the console?  You'll have to scroll up past all of the trace lines to get to the original error.

Comment: I'm guessing there's a problem with `makePipes`.  Can you post your `makePipes` function?

Comment: Make sure that the `makePipes` method exists and has no parameters or if it does have a parameter (e.g., `sender:AnyObject`), change the `selector` argument to `Selector("makePipes:")`.

Comment: Thank you, I see now that my problem was with the selector function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With Swift you don't define selectors using `Selector`, you just pass a string. So you would use the following:

```
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self,
        selector: "makePipes", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

This assumes `makePipes` takes no parameters. If it expects the timer to be passed as a parameter, you would code it as `"makePipes:"`.